# Intersection of Object Attributes in Python

Tags: python, object, set, intersection

So I made 2 sets of objects, like such.

```
class 4digits:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.first = (value - (value % 100)) / 100
        self.last = value % 100
```

These are all 4 digits objects, so it would be like...

```
object.value = 1234
object.first = 12
object.last = 34
```

if I had 2 sets, set1 and set2, I'd like to update set1 and set2 to only contain the objects where set1 has a last attribute that matches to set2's first attribute.

Such as...
1234 in set1 will match to 3456 in set 2.

I could do this as a list instead of a set pretty easily but a set feels a lot more efficient if I could figure out the procedure, but not sure how I can return an intersection of object's attributes. Any help.

Edited: Because I was asked for code, and my hypothetical wasn't exactly what I was actually doing.

Thanks to Jez I got this answer:

```
def lastinfirst(list1, list2):
    firsts = set( l2.first for l2 in list2)
    newlist1 = [ l1 for l1 in list1 if l1.last in firsts]
    return newlist1

def firstinlast(list1, list2):
    lasts = set( l1.last for l1 in list1)
    newlist2 = [ l2 for l2 in list2 if l2.first in lasts]
    return newlist2
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to show a bit more code to help us understand your problem.  Since we don't really know the types of `haverooms.borough` and `wantrooms.borough`, it makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: If you don't want to do it "brute force" you'll have to implement the same idea like [DB index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), meaning, whenever a new person is being added to `haverooms` or to `wantrooms` the insertion will also update an additional data-structure in case this person is `borough`. This way you can quickly iterate only on the "relevant" people when you're looking for a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly what you want, this should do it:

```
# Get the set of unique boroughs in which people want rooms:
wantedboroughs = set( w.borough for w in wantrooms )

# Get all records for people who have rooms in those boroughs:
result = [ h for h in haverooms if h.borough in wantedboroughs ]
```

Well, now you've edited your question to not be about rooms and boroughs at all. But maybe you can generalize the principles exemplified here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I can generalize it. That was the idea, just wanted the general example so I could work it for my specific problem, and I think the example I gave was easier to understand. It seems to be working so far.

Comment: I solved it using your concept to make 2 functions. Edited in the answer above.

Comment: Fwiw I think you did a good job of boiling it down to a hypothetical: your first question was easier to understand than the second, at least to me. But yes, on SO there's this principle whereby questions are unwelcome if you don't show how you've attempted to solve it yourself.